# Java 8: multiple casting with &

Tags: java, casting, java-8

I was looking into the source code of [`Comparator#comparing()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) from JDK 1.8, and the casting of lambda was a surprise for me:

```
//declaration
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)  // <- this cast here
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

After reading that

> The returned comparator is serializable if the specified function is also serializable.

and some playing with the code, I figured out why this works and why it wouldn't work if the cast was different.

My question is: **What is this `(A & B)` multiple casting?**

By googling `java multiple cast` I found only multiple casting using `(A)(B)`. Is there like an article about adding this in JDK `1.8`?

Comment: It's been there since 1.5, it's just not used very often.

Comment: I meant if the `(A)(B)` cast was used or if the cast wasn't there at all.

Comment: @yshavit: interesting, my Eclipse 4.4 says `Additional bounds are not allowed in cast operator at source levels below 1.8` if i change the jdk version to 1.7 (But Eclipse could be wrong of course)

Comment: For the cast with &, I found that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16 and the diff with 1.7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8-diffs.pdf and from this one, it seems it was already there in 1.7. But I don't understand the usage here ?

Comment: From your "1.7" diff: `Specification: JSR-337 Java® SE 8 Release Contents` (2nd page, also `se8` in URL). Moreover there is nothing babout this in the [1.7 version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16). But thanks a lot, this is exacly what i wanted.

Comment: Intersection bounds have been permitted in *type variable bounds* since generics were introduced.  Java 8 extended this to functional interface target types for lambdas and method references.